# My created executable file will not run because it can't find the XML-files

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, executable

I have been working on a big project, and today I tried to make an executable from it with microsoft visual studio 2010. This worked, but when try to run it the program will stop. This is probably because my function "public List load(int levelnumber)" cant find a projectpath. Because this one is made meanwhile compiling. My XML are in C:\test4\myLevels\ and my exe is in my C:\test folder. I put the myLevels folder with the XML files in the C:\test4\ folder by myself. Sorry for my bad english. Any help is welcome!

Error (in dutch, no idea how to change this to english):

```
Bestanden die helpen bij het beschrijven van het probleem: 
C:\Users\woutr\AppData\Local\Temp\WER9F14.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml 
C:\Users\woutr\AppData\Local\Temp\WERD03.tmp.appcompat.txt 
C:\Users\woutr\AppData\Local\Temp\WERD81.tmp.mdmp Lees de 
onlineprivacyverklaring: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0413
Als de onlineprivacyverklaring niet beschikbaar is, lees dan onze 
offlineprivacyverklaring: C:\Windows\system32\nl-NL\erofflps.txt
```

Photo of how the error looks like: imgur.com/77iAOGe

XML class:

```
public class XML
{
    public void Save(List<Sprite> sprites, int levelnumber)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Sprite>));
        CreateDirectory("myLevels");
        using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"myLevels\level_" + levelnumber + ".xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, sprites);
        }
    }

    public List<Sprite> load(int levelnumber)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Sprite>));
        using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"myLevels\level_" + levelnumber + ".xml"))
        {
            List<Sprite> sprites = (List<Sprite>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            return sprites;
        }
    }

    private void CreateDirectory(string path)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: It looks like your code was basically written for use *while running in Visual Studio* rather than taking into consideration the structure when it's running "normally". It's not at all clear where you *want* the XML files to be found, to be honest - creating a new directory wherever you happen to be running may well not be a good idea. (And why are you creating `myLevels` in the current directory, then trying to dump XML  files into a potentially entirely different directory under x86/debug?

Comment: just curious. why are you doing this: `Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(...`, two times the same function...

Comment: Hmmmm I see what you mean, I am very bad with XML but im going to rewrite the code and see if I can make it better and maybe even working. I already refactered a bit

Comment: @JonSkeet Could you give me a bit more help on how to change to code? I dont get it worknig and running yet.

Comment: This isn't really specific to XML at all. You need to have a clearer idea in your own mind of where you want to store the files, and what that should be relative to. Note that the current working directory may be *entirely* different from "where the executable lives".

Comment: I tried to create a directory this way: "CreateDirectory(@"c:\test\myLevels");" But it just doens't create it at all